# page sliding in mobile web aplications with fingers

Tags: php, android, mysql, jquery-mobile, uislider

Is there a way to slide between pages in mobile web applications instead of clicking a button or a link? I did alot search non of the mobile web frameworks have this feature. how is that possible to do it? Or can I coonect to my PHP or my (MYSQL) database directly from an application in Android without (webview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery Mobile site](http://jquerymobile.com) (especially the [Events section](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html)) or its big brother [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Additionally, [Apache Cordova](http://www.phonegap.com) - formerly known as **PhoneGap** - may of of help.

Comment: I looked at JQuery Mobile it's not supporting slide with fingers.